# Check URL status code without $http, $ajax or jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Is it possible to check the status code of an extenal URL without using $http, $ajax or jQuery but rather something very simple?

Answer (score 1):

You could use hurl.it which is a free web resource to send requests to custom urls, using a defined (get,post,put,patch, head, delete, options) and the url of your choice with or without custom headers in a friendly form.  Then it shows the entire response in a screen below.  Similar to Chrome Dev Tools, but unlike Chrome Dev Tools, you can make your own typed in urls on the fly and without having to understand any of the outbound modules offered in various JS flavors. Link Here: (https://www.hurl.it/)

*You can also add parameters, or auth tokens it's a really sweet free web app that I've used to hack some AJAX calls and create some nice PhantomJS request modules.

You'll notice right @ the top of the response view is:
GET https://www.google.com/

200 OK       152.95 kB       56 ms

*200 OK being your status codes on the URL "https://www.google.com/" I hope it helps!